# How to auto-hibernate computer when it overheats?

Tags: windows-7, overheating

I'm running Windows 7 on an [Acer Aspire 4937G](http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx?modelId=1091) and there is this issue that whenever I run too many programs simultaneously, my laptop will auto-shutdown due to overheating.

I was wondering is there anyway to make it auto-hibernate instead of auto-shutdown when it's overheated (to prevent loss of unsaved data due to sudden shutdown)?

Comment: Does it perform the standard shutdown process, or does it just shut off instantly?

Comment: @grawity The screen blacks out and I suspect it shuts down instantly, however I'm not sure if there's something running at a lower level.

Comment: Then it's triggered by the hardware, not something you can tune in Windows -- only have a program that hibernates *before* the shutdown.

Comment: I know your question is about auto-hibernating, but have you looked at why the laptop is overheating in the first place? Continued overheating is going to shorten the life of the CPU and could result in permanent failure.

Comment: You should fix the broken hardware ( clogged vent, dead fan, improperly seated heat sink ) so that it doesn't overheat in the first place.

Comment: @CharlieRB It's running too many programs. For example sometimes I have over 200 tabs running on Chrome. Chrome has its own "auto-save" when the computer crashes (which is cool), but other programs that are opened will have their unsaved data lost.

Comment: @psusi How do I check if the hardware is broken?

Comment: @Pacerier, if it is overheating, then by definition, something is broken.

Comment: @Pacerier, yes it was nice when Chrome did autosave tabs, but Chrome unfortunately stopped this 1 or 2 years after your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by using `Speedfan`.

In the Speedfan configuration you can create Events to fire on specific triggers, e.g. on CPU temperature > 65°C. You can add a script to be executed when this event is triggered, so you could create a batch file which puts the computer to sleep/standby/hibernate before the "critical" temperature is reached where it auto shuts down.

Comment: Btw does Windows 7 itself have any form of temperature protection *settings*?

Comment: Windows 7 does not come with a feature like this. If the Computer shuts down normally this would be due to some driver/software, if it simply turns of it is something at a lower level like the BIOS or the CPU itself turning off due to overheating

Answer (score 1):

***Whole comment removed by user due to an issue with a URL provided that was posted as called a Psying Site*** It seems that the URL was incorrect and or invalid and caused an incident to one or more users who has viewed this answer. I apologize for any inconvenience this answer may have caused. Please note that any comments towards any answers are taken seriously whether true or false as issues that may cause other users discomfort of any form whatsoever will be taken down by the user whom posts it. **Error 404 Answer Not Found**

Comment: BEWARE: GRAVE DANGEROUS PHISHING on CoreTemp.

Comment: BEWARE: GRAVE DANGEROUS PHISHING on CoreTemp
http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp skipped all parasite offerings
Later a Chrome tab from a great FR financial site offered an iPhone 6s for 1 EUR, 100 left, 3h left, plenty serious comments explaining it. Conditions cleverly written induced me in confidence, I entered Credit Card (the only way offered). Then received an email from funkyclock.com about the games offerings but NOTHING about the iPhone. This is when I noticed the forged spoofed URL. And I don't know, on Sunday night, how to make my credit card protected. Very clever. BEWARE